# opengl, textures have always the same size

Tags: opengl, textures, image-scaling

I'm trying to apply a texture to a vertex array whit the following code:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texcoords);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, faceIndices);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

with this texture:
[image: texture]

so i have this result:
[image: Result]

Now I'm wondering how can I scale the floor texture, i've already tried to scale the texture with photoshop, but the result is the same but heavier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your texture coordinates how you want to map the texture.
Let take example,it cover the whole polygon

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Now if you want to repeat the texture five times then provide coordinates like `

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(5.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(5.0f, 5.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 5.0f);`
```

Like above example change the value how you want to map the texture.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean you want the texture to tile less, or tile more. In which case, change your texture coordinates, not the texture (i.e. whatever data is in `texcoords`).

Also, your example texture is blue, but it's brown in the rendered image. You might be swapping the R+B channels when loading.

Comment: also thank you for the swapping channel hint, i haven't even noticed :)